# How to force vim to interpret file as dos-format

Tags: gvim

I am using vim to view XML files created by a Windows app.  It is probably a malformed XML file because vim thinks it's opening a Unix file format.  So I end up seeing `^M` at the end of almost every line.

I don't want to mess with the file, as vim is the only viewer.  It is going to be used by other apps, and in fact, may even be in the middle of being written to.  I just want vim to interpret `<CR><LF>` as a Unix carriage return.  In case it matters, I typically open files with either

```
 :e path/to/file
 :split path/to/file
 :vsplit path/to/file
```

or I might use the netrw plugin.  I am using vim 7.4, patches 1-729, built for Cygwin.  It is not easy to upgrade in my environment.

P.S. Sorry if the tag is not quite.  The posting web page suggested original-vim, but that tag doesn't seem to exist.  No other tags in the suggestion list seemed any more appropriate.  I am open to suggestions as to a better tag.

Comment: Do you want to automatically do `set ff=dos` for these files? If so, please add how these files can be identified (location, extension or some other detail)

Comment: One solution is to execute `:set ffs=dos` before opening the file.

Comment: `:e ++ff=dos yourfile`

Comment: @muru: Yes, I want to set ff=dos, but not after opening the file for edit, otherwise it effectively modifies the file.

Comment: @garyjohn: That's a possibility.  It means opening the new window (for those cases where I open a new window) then setting ffs, then editing the file.

Comment: @Chrisian Brabandt: Yes, that's it.  If I already have the file open, I can issue `:e ++f=dos %`.  Thanks!  Did you want to enter this in as the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Christan Brabandt for the solution:

```
:e ++ff=dos filename
```

If the file is already opened in unix file format:

```
:e ++ff=dos %
```

Or just:

```
:e ++ff=dos
```

If I change the file format option, the buffer/file is marked as modified.  This makes sense since the changes include things like using different characters in the electronic file to represent a newline.

Comment: What does it do? Is it only a view change or does it change the content? Can you [update your answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/11169/edit) with an explanation (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar)?

Comment: I just re-read your comment, and augmented the answer.  Thanks.